# What kind of residuals should we test for linear mixed-effects models (LMER)?

Tags: r, regression, lme4-nlme, residuals, normality-assumption

I'm on a journey trying to get my mind around the normality of residuals assumption for linear mixed-effects models, this is a [FOLLOW-UP POST](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/588224/lmer-violating-residuals-normality-assumption-what-should-i-do-when-enough-d/588227?noredirect=1#comment1087055_588227)

While studying to better understand what I could do to solve the non-normality problem, I came across different types of residuals such as [standartized or studentized](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/204708/is-studentized-residuals-v-s-standardized-residuals-in-lm-model) or [conditional or marginal](https://www.ime.usp.br/%7Ejmsinger/MAE0610/Nobre&Singer2007Rcommands.pdf) residuals, for example. (also, ref. Field, 2012, chapter 7)

```
mod1 <- lmer(SCORE ~ X1_c * X2 + (1|PARTICIPANT), data = data)
```

With [THIS](https://github.com/Larissa-Cury/dataPostSeptember8th) dataset. (this is a Git link)

```
### model residuals:

myResiduals <- tibble(residuals = resid(mod1)) ### this is the function I've been using so far

### std and studentized residuals:

myResiduals$standardized.residuals <- rstandard(mod1)  ### doesn't work: error message
myResiduals$studentized.residuals  <-rstudent(mod1)    ### works
```

- Simply put, my question is: **am I testing the normality assumption on the right type of residuals for this model?** Any thoughts would be much appreciated! Thanks in advance.